# Getting post and attached image from subdomain

Tags: posts, customization, sidebar, subdomains

I Recently installed wordpress as subdomain on my main website. Now i have two installations:
www.example.com and www.example.com/store/. Now i want my Main domain to show recent posts from subdomain in the sidebar of main site.

All i want is:

post->url
post->title
post->thumbnail

getting post url and title was very easy with the following code "

```
$products = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT * FROM store_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'post' LIMIT 4" );
```

My both WordPress installations share the same database but different prefixes and only one image is attached each post (not using featured image function, just attaching image to post)

I don't have much idea for how to join and do custom queries. Kindly help in his regard.

Comment: Why are you running two different wordpress installations if you need data access from one to the other?

Comment: I tried MU but my host doesn't support it, so had to install another WP.

Comment: Why not just use a custom post type?

Comment: i need total subdomain with seperate database tables....

Comment: I know this sounds a little cheap, but you should consider to change the host...

Answer (score 1):

Sum of the comments/possible solutions plus a third option:

- Would be possible with a WP MU installation (doesn't work because of host)
- Custom Post Types (for some reason the OP needs separated DB)
- There also is the [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) built into WP.